# Pie chart in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I have a dropdown in which i have dropdown values as Zone and State.
Now when i select Zone from the dropdown then iam displaying a pie chart with zone values and on select of pie chart section
iam displaying only the selected zone values in a table.

(for example if i select south section from the pie chart then only the south zone records will be displayed in table).

That i have done.

But  when i select the State from the dropdown the pie chart with state values is displaying but on click of pie chart section the records are not displaying in the table.

So far i have used these code............

```js
var oEvDataSet = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset("EV_REPORT_DATASET", {

    dimensions: [{
        name: "ZONE",
        axis: 1,
        value: "{Key}"
    }],

    measures: [{

        name: "NUMBER",
        value: "{Number}"
    }],

    data: {

        path: "EVENTREPORT>/ZONE"
            //path: "EVENTREPORT>/Category"

    }

});

var line = new sap.viz.ui5.Pie({

    width: "60%",
    height: "500px",
    dataset: oEvDataSet

});


var fSelectionChanged = function(oEvent) {
    var data = this.selection();
    // var country,dso;
    var dataFilter = [];
    for (i in data) {
        var zone = data[i].data.ZONE;
        //var state = data[i].data.STATE;
        // state = data[i].data.STATE;
        dataFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("ZONE", "EQ", zone));

        //dataFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("STATE","EQ",state));
    }
    for (i in eventReportAllFilter) {
        dataFilter.push(eventReportAllFilter[i]);

        // dataFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("STATE","EQ",state));
    }

    //dataFilter.push(eventReportAllFilter);
    Ev_oTable_AllVenues.bindRows('AM_EventList>/eventlist', oERZoneSorter, dataFilter);
};

line.attachSelectData(fSelectionChanged);
line.attachDeselectData(fSelectionChanged);
line.attachInitialized(function() {});
oER_VerLayout.addContent(line);
```

[image: Pie Chart]

U can also see in the image.

In the image if i select dropdown value as state the pie chart is displaying but on select of pie chart section the values are not displaying in the table.

How can i do this..??

Please help me on this.

Thanks
Sathish

Comment: we cannot see your image

Comment: if i insert an image its showing an error as you must have atleast 10 reputations to upload images

Comment: upload here http://tinypic.com/ and give me the image url and i will edit it for you

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/bea542/8

Comment: Hi, where did you define eventReportAllFilter and why did you comment out the code of filter for State?